# Getting the user who ran the SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

In my SSIS package I have the need to know what the windows user ID is of the user who executed the package.

I wrote an SSIS package that is manually executed from within a WPF application and I need to know the windows UserId.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to use the username of the person that executed the package you can use this built in system variable:

```
@[System::UserName]
```

If the logged in user needs to be used in a `Script Task` you can do it this way:

```
Dts.Variables("System::UserName").Value
```

**NOTE** The full path (domain + userid) is returned. You may need to use string functions to extract the userid from the domain.